# How to pass a route to Azure function (C#) http trigger in Data Factory pipeline?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I need to pass header information in Azure Function activity in Data Factory.
As can be seen in the picture, the header is marked in red.

I need to change the following code to receive the header. I also need to capture the value of the header.

public static async Task Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = "{name}" )] HttpRequestMessage req,
            string name,
            TraceWriter log,
            [Blob("pk-api-test/{name}", FileAccess.Read)] Stream myBlob)

[image]

Comment: Do you mean you don't want to use `Route` anymore, instead, you want to pass header info to http trigger and capture the info to retrieve blob?

Comment: Yes @JerryLiu that's what I wanted to do.

Comment: @JerryLiu This threw me an error. So, I solved it by using 'Route = TestFunction/ {name}' in the code and in the Azure function settings in Data Factory, I used the Function Name = TestFunction/albany

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by using 'Route = TestFunction/{name}' in the code and in the Azure function settings in Data Factory, I used the Function Name = TestFunction/albany

Answer (score 0):

Have a try at code below. Use `headers` to access headers info in http request.

```
   public static async Task Run(
         [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req,
         [Blob("pk-api-test/{headers.name}", FileAccess.Read)]Stream myBlob, 
         IDictionary<string, string> headers,
         TraceWriter log)
   {
       string name = headers["name"];
       //...
   }
```

Comment: Just leave my answer here hence it works in my test with data factory.